# Scikit-Image Questions (specifically re: `blob_log`)

Tags: python, arrays, image, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm trying to use blob detection in scikit-image. `blob_log` is supposed to return an array of either Nx3 for a 2D image, or an Nx4 for a 3D image (?) The first two values in a 2D image are the (x, y, sigma) and in 3D are (p, x, y sigma)

I'm attempting to load [this image](http://www.edvotek.com/223_gallery.pnghttp://static.tumblr.com/7fef8cca093bc3e0578dd21518a7f6c2/lvprlax/ss6njg6yw/tumblr_static_91hvez0yov0gcgswckkw40swc.png) into my code which looks like it has quite a few observable blobs & it is a 2D image.

**I've got a few questions:**

(1) the `blob_log` is returning a Nx4 array which means its loading it as a 3D image. When I try to print it, it looks like its just a bunch of empty arrays which I don't understand how because when I `plt.show()` it is a 2D image.

(2) If N is the number of blobs it has calculated, then it is only giving me less than 10% of the total images - I believe this is due to the fact that the image is on a white background making it more difficult for the `blob_log` to notice - is that correct?

(3) I don't understand how the for loop at the end of the [Blob documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_blob.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-features-detection-plot-blob-py) works? How is it plotting the circles over the image? I'm sorry if this is an elementary question, but its frustrating me because I think that would help me with some of the other things I was wondering about.

**Attempts to figure out what is going on:**

(1) Loading `data.coins()` and printing it gives me a nice array of values which I assume are the 2D, it still doesn't explain why the image I want to load isn't being recognized as 2D.

(2) I tried to load the `data.coins()` which should be an obviously provided image with circular images and fooled around with the sigma and threshold settings, I'm getting a variety of different values depending on the settings - is there a good way of figuring out which are the best without having to fool around with the settings until I get one that works?

Due to the length of my code and my question, below is just the applicable parts, but my entire code can be [found here](https://pastebin.com/CDQrLf42)

```
from skimage import data, feature, exposure, io
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = data.coins()
#img = io.imread('gfp_test.png') #this is the image I linked above just in my dir
print(img)
print(type(img))
A = feature.blob_log(imgG, max_sigma = 30, num_sigma = 10, threshold = .4)

print (A)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The link to your image is broken, can you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You have a color image, while `blob_*` expect a grayscale image. Use `skimage.color.rgb2gray` to convert your image to grayscale before using the blob finding functions. See our [crash course on NumPy for images](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html) for more details.

(2) Let's see if the above fixes your problem. I think blob finding is a local operation, so the white frame around the edges is probably not a problem.

(3) Yes, the variable naming could be clearer. The key is here: `sequence = zip(blobs_list, colors, titles)`. If you look at what those individual variables are, they are length-3 lists with the results from the three different blob-finding methods, three different colors, and three different titles (the names of the three methods). So the outer for-loop is iterating through the methods, and the three panels of the figure. (You should look at the [matplotlib documentation for subplots](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) for more on this.)

The inner loop, then, is going through the results of a single blob-finding method and putting a circle around each result. You'll see the x/y transposed, and this is a consequence of the different coordinate conventions between our images (see the crash course linked above) and the matplotlib canvas. Then we [create a circle](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html) with the appropriate radius for each blob, and add it to the matplotlib axes. See the examples linked from the Circle documentation for more information on adding patches.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I has a few follow up questions (sorry!)

`
imgG = rgb2gray(img)

A = feature.blob_log(imgG, max_sigma = 30, threshold = .01)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

ax.imshow(img)
x = A[:, 0]
y = A[:, 1]
r = A[:, 2]
for xx, yy in zip(x, y):
    c = Circle((xx, yy), r,  fill = False)
    ax.add_patch(c)

plt.show()

` 
I though this would work (I get a ValueError: Setting Array element with sequence)  but in the documentation they have a `y, x, r = blob` which I think negates this?

Comment: The Code is quite messy please [see here](https://pastebin.com/jYyAVCHY)
I though this would work (I get a ValueError: Setting Array element with sequence)  but in the documentation they have a `y, x, r = blob` which I think negates this?